# Would Upgrading Postgres on CentOS Break It?

Tags: centos, postgresql

I am trying to install PostgreSQL server on my CentOS machine. From what I read here
(https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/upgrading.html) It seems like Postgres does not guarantee backward compatibility of its files. When I checked CentOS base repo, it said the current version of `postgresql-server` is `9.2.23` which is many versions behind upstream. I wonder what will happen when major version upgrade is released on CentOS and I run `yum update` as usual. Will it render my database in unusable state? If so, what is the best approach to prevent it from happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I wonder what will happen when major version upgrade is released on CentOS

This will not happen. One of the core principles of RHEL/CentOS is that packages never get a major version upgrade, or an upgrade which would result in breaking changes (or that's the intent, as occasionally a breaking change might make its way in).

If you want to upgrade PostgreSQL, use the official [PostgreSQL Yum repos](https://yum.postgresql.org/repopackages.php#pg10). These packages install their files in a separate location, to where you could run multiple different versions simultaneously on the same server if you so desired.